# How to convert tf.int64 to tf.float32?

Tags: tensorflow, int64

I tried:

```
test_image = tf.convert_to_tensor(img, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Then following error appears:

```
ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float32 for Tensor with dtype int64: 'Tensor("test/ArgMax:0", shape=TensorShape([Dimension(None)]), dtype=int64)'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Oops, I find the function in the API...

```
 tf.to_float(x, name='ToFloat')
```

Comment: `tf.to_float()` is now deprecated and `tf.cast()` should be used instead.

Answer (score 58):

You can cast generally using:

```
tf.cast(my_tensor, tf.float32)
```

Replace tf.float32 with your desired type.

---

**Edit**: It seems at the moment at least, that `tf.cast` won't cast to an unsigned dtype (e.g. `tf.uint8`). To work around this, you can cast to the signed equivalent and used `tf.bitcast` to get all the way. e.g.

```
tf.bitcast(tf.cast(my_tensor, tf.int8), tf.uint8)
```

Comment: It should be noted that tf cannot compute gradients for these operations, so they cannot be used to simulate quantized weights.

Answer (score 5):

You can use either [`tf.cast(x, tf.float32)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#cast) or [`tf.to_float(x)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#to_float), both of which cast to float32.

Example:

```python
sess = tf.Session()

# Create an integer tensor.
tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), dtype=tf.int64)
sess.run(tensor)
# array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

# Use tf.cast()
tensor_float = tf.cast(tensor, tf.float32)
sess.run(tensor_float)
# array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.], dtype=float32)

# Use tf.to_float() to cast to float32
tensor_float = tf.to_float(tensor)
sess.run(tensor_float)
# array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: when I cast an mage with type of `tf.uint8` to `tf.float32`, and used `matplotlib` to show them, `tf.float32` change. How can show the main image?

Answer (score 1):

`image`type cast you can use `tf.image.convert_image_dtype()` which convert image range `[0 255]` to `[0 1]`:

```
img_uint8 = tf.constant([1,2,3], dtype=tf.uint8)
img_float = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img_uint8, dtype=tf.float32)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    _img= sess.run([img_float])
    print(_img, _img.dtype)
```

output:

```
[0.00392157 0.00784314 0.01176471] float32
```

if you only want to cast type and keep value range use `tf.cast` or `tf.to_float` as @stackoverflowuser2010 and @Mark McDonald answered

Answer (score 1):

In case your data is actually a **Pandas** dataframe, we can first check for the datatype using:

```
print(dataset.dtypes)
```

To cast all the entries into `float32` (for e.g.),

```
# Typecast
dataset = dataset.astype('float32')

#print them to verify
print(dataset.dtypes)
```