# How to tf.cast a field within a tensorflow Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, casting, tensorflow-datasets

I have a `tf.data.Dataset` that looks like this:

```
<BatchDataset shapes: ((None, 256, 256, 3), (None,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.int32)>
```

The 2nd element (1st if zero indexing) corresponds with a label.  I want to cast the 2nd term (labels) to `tf.uint8`.

How can one use `tf.cast` when dealing with `td.data.Dataset`?

---

**Similar Questions**

[How to convert tf.int64 to tf.float32?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35596629/11163122) is very similar, but is not for a `tf.data.Dataset`.

---

**Repro**

From [Image classification from scratch](https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_from_scratch/):

```bash
curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/E/1/3E1C3F21-ECDB-4869-8368-6DEBA77B919F/kagglecatsanddogs_5340.zip
unzip kagglecatsanddogs_5340.zip
```

Then in Python with `tensorflow~=2.4`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "PetImages", batch_size=32
)
print(ds)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `map` function may help

```
a = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.empty((2,5,3)))
b = tf.data.Dataset.range(5, 8)
c = tf.data.Dataset.zip((a,b))
d = c.batch(1)
d
<BatchDataset shapes: ((None, 5, 3), (None,)), types: (tf.float64, tf.int64)>

# change the dtype of the 2nd arg in the batch from int64 to int8
e = d.map(lambda x,y:(x,tf.cast(y, tf.int8))) 
<MapDataset shapes: ((None, 5, 3), (None,)), types: (tf.float64, tf.int8)>
```